# Typescript generic type unknown arguments count

Tags: typescript, function, generics, arguments

I'm trying to make a function with a generic type that takes a function, an array of its arguments, then apply them to it, but typescript doesn't interpret the args type correctly

```js
  const animate = async <P, A>(
    action: (payload: P) => any,
    algorithm: (...args: A[]) => P[],
    args: A[]
  ) => {
    if (state.playing) return;
    dispatch(togglePlaying());
    const sequence = algorithm(...args);
    for (let element of sequence) {
      await delay(1);
      dispatch(action(element));
    }
    dispatch(togglePlaying());
  };
```

Here is the error I get when trying to use it

Argument of type '(rows: number, cols: number, startCell: Coordinates, endCell: Coordinates) => GridT[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: (number | Coordinates)[]) => GridT[]'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the `Parameters<Type>` type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype

> Constructs a tuple type from the types used in the parameters of a function type Type.

Then, you can define your function like this:

```js
const animate = async <P, F extends (...args: any[]) => P[]>(
    action: (payload: P) => any,
    algorithm: F,
    args: Parameters<F>
) => {
    // blah
}
```

As your error message shows, if you define the type of `algorithm` as `(...args: A[]) => P[]`, you're essentially saying every argument is of the same type (in your case `number | Coordinates`), so when you try to pass in a function of type `(rows: number, cols: number, startCell: Coordinates, endCell: Coordinates) => GridT[]` it doesn't match.